# Critique my Python Package Structure

Tags: python, module, package, init

I'm in the process of finishing up a Python package I've been writing. However, before I release it I'd like to get some feedback on the overall structure of the package as well as the `__init__.py` file.

This should give an idea of what my `__init__.py` file looks like.

```
'''
A docsting describing the package.
'''

__author__     = myname
__copyright__  = mycopyright
__credits__    = listofcredits
__license__    = mylicense
__version__    = 0.0
__maintainer__ = me
__email__      = myemail
__status__     = indevelopment

# This contains a module with directories as strings (for file reference)
import mypath

# some modules
import this
import that

# some gui widget classes
from windowmodule import windowwidget
from widgetmodule import someguiwidget
from someothermodule import someotherguiwidget, andanotherguiwidget

def __demo__ () :
    # a demo of the package

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    __demo__()
```

This should give a decent idea of the overall package structure.

```
mypackage/
    mypath.py
    __init__.py
    license.txt
    readme.txt
    modules/
        this.py
        that.py
    windows/
        windowmodule.py
    widgets/
        widgetmodule.py
    images/
        imagefiles.whatever
    tools/
        tools.py
```

Comment: This is probably better for [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use absolute imports instead of relative imports, e.g. `import mypackage.mypath as mypath`.

Comment: ...why?  Is this a personal preference?